# tableView:viewForTableColumn:row: not called

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, appkit

I am new to AppKit but not to UIKit.
I try to use an `NSTableView` and I want to populate programmatically.

So I implement

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row{
    return nil;
}
```

and I set my class as the delegate and datasource in Interface Builder.
`numberOfRowsInTableView` is called but `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:` is not called.

If I add

```
-(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex{
    return @"toto";
}
```

this one is called.

If I understand, `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:` is called for View-Based tables and `tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:` is called for Cell-Based tables.

How can I define that my table is View-Based ?

**Edited:**
ok ... so the problem is I am using 10.6 and tableView:viewForTableColumn:row: is available since 10.7. So it means before 10.7 there is only Cell-Based tables ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Interface Builder, in the Attributes inspector pane (Cmd-Opt-4), set the table view type to View Based. It is Cell Based by default.

You have to select the table view in either in the left-hand object view or by clicking on it in the editor. Notice that the first time you click on it in the editor, it will select the scroll view, so you will have to click on it a second time to get it to select the table view object.

I believe you need Xcode 4.3 or newer for the OS X 10.7 SDK, and hence view-based tables views, to be available.

Comment: ok ... so the problem is I am using 10.6 and tableView:viewForTableColumn:row: is available since 10.7. So it means before 10.7 there is only Cell-Based tables ?

Comment: Yes, exactly, if you are targeting 10.6, you need to use cell-based table views.

Comment: Ok ... thanks again ... I'll have to read more documentation I think.

Comment: Is there a way to set the 'Content Based' property programmatically? I do not have any XIBs.